# Change option element according to conditions

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have dropdown list which iterates a python list and display it

```
<select name="choose" id="choose1">
{%for item in products%}
 <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
 {%endfor%}
</select>
```

This list includes all the product's name and I have another list which includes all the ratings of the products.

Here's the rating and product

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="productname">Product's Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" name="productname" placeholder="Enter Product's Name"
        style="text-align: center;">
    </div>
    <div class="rating">
      <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
      <select name="rating" id="rating">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>⭐

    </div>
```

This one's in flask

```
@app.route('/search_logged')
def search_logged():
    return render_template('search_logged.html',products = product, ratings =rating)
    search_value = request.form.get('searchbar')
```

And I want to display the product's name if their rating is equal to san integer value.

Is there anyway to do it using javascript or python?

Comment: It is very hard to guess the connection between "choose", "rating" and product name in the code you have posted. Where would a JavaScript get a rating and a product name from and what would it compare the rating to? Please read [ask] and [mcve] and decide if you want to do this on the client or the server

Comment: I can suggest to write a javascript and ajax for on change function to get dynamic data.